# Using objectid in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform

I have a JavaScript table getting parse data need to use the objectid of each row for a later date need to store them in variable or something like that

Can any help me.

Cheers

UPDATE 1

Here is some code to help

```
var firstTeamResults = Parse.Object.extend(strUser);
var query = new Parse.Query(firstTeamResults);

query.startsWith("NameGame", ask4);
query.descending("updateAt");
query.find(
{
    success: function(results)
    {        
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
        {
            var object = results[i];

            (function($) {
                $("#first-team-results-table").append("<tr><td>" 
                    + object.get("NameGame") 
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + object.get("item") 
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + "<input id='video' type='submit' value='Video'/>"
                    + "</td><td>"
                    + object.get("des") 
                    + "</td><td>" 
                    + object.get("group") 
                    + "</td><td>"
                    + "<input id='more' type='submit' value='More'/>"
                    + "</td></tr>");
            })(jQuery);
       }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
})
});
```

Comment: This is incredibly broad, could you elaborate some more or show us some code?

Comment: Just like `object.get("NameGame")`, you can just do `object.id` to get the unique id of that object. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to ask. After you query the objects and get them, you can just call the .id method on each object to get the objectId.

See the example below.

```
var YourClass = Parse.Object.extend("YourClassName");
var query = new Parse.Query(YourClass);

//An unconstrained Query to get all objects in the table
query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    for(var i=0; i <results.length; i++){
      var objectId = results[i].id //This returns you the objectId of each row
      //You can do what you want with objectId now.
    }
  },
  error: function(object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

The [Parse Docs](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#objects-retrieving-objects) show that you can retrieve the three special properties of every object by using the methods below.

```
var objectId = yourObject.id;
var updatedAt = yourObject.updatedAt;
var createdAt = yourObject.createdAt;
```

Comment: Hi @CodeWalker Sorry it has taken a while to get back to you i am sorry to say the following code doesn't work. Do you have any other advice?